# With cte and rownumber performance

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table vente(sales) which contains over than 350 000 000. I tried to execute the following query but it took a long time:

```
 select t1.[datecol],t1.[Prix de vente TTC],t1.Quantité 
      from [Vente] t1
      inner join (select distinct [datecol],[Code Article],[Code Structure],[Code Site],
      row_number() over(Partition by  [Code Article],[Code Structure],[Code Site] order by [datecol]desc ) as rn

      from (select distinct  [datecol],[Code Article],[Code Structure],[Code Site]
           from [Vente] t2
            where promo = 0
                  and ([Code Article] is not null) 
                  and ([Code Structure] is not null) 
                  and ([Prix de Revient] is not null)
    )g
          ) a
           on a.datecol=t1.datecol
            and t1.[Code Article] = a.[Code Article]
            and t1.[Code Structure]=a.[Code Structure]
            and t1.[Code Site]=a.[Code Site]
            where  promo = 0
            and (t1.[Code Article] is not null) and (t1.[Code Structure] is not null) and ([Prix de Revient] is not null ) 
            and
              rn <= 28
```

the execution plan

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that's the price of `row_number`. It's not searching - it's sorting and building a new column. It's like you are saying *"you know nothing, sql server! let me show you what dates you have and how to compute the desc order. this date goes with number one, this is two,..."*

I saw previous posts with plans, there were some indexes mentioned, so lets try this (please post plan picture of it):

```
select t1.[datecol],t1.[Prix de vente TTC],t1.Quantité 
from [Vente] t1
outer apply
(
  select top 28 distinct t2.[datecol]
  from [Vente] t2
  where t2.[Code Article] = t1.[Code Article]
    and t2.[Code Structure]=t1.[Code Structure]
    and t2.[Code Site]=t1.[Code Site]
  order by t2.[datecol] desc
) t2
where t1.promo = 0
  and (t1.[Code Article] is not null)
  and (t1.[Code Structure] is not null) 
  and (t1.[Prix de Revient] is not null ) 
  and t1.datecol = t2.datecol
```

I'm not sure of your final goal and what are actual requirements (about those "28days"). Another approach is to find out days first, store'em in temp table, then join.

As I already mentioned, I don't know the requirement so can't say if all the task can be accomplished with applying a straightforward simple filter
`where t1.datecol >= dateadd(dd, -28, cast(getdate() as date))` - but I'd recommend to think of it.

But  somehow I'm sure that you don't need data older than a year ago. Apply this filter, cut off data you don't need for sure. Compute `set @startdate = dateadd(yy, -1, getdate())` (may be less than a year) and apply this filter to both inner and outer query. This will cut off huge amount of data you don't need to process.

Right now you do not have any filters except `promo=0` and calculated date filter, so you process almost all of those 350M records. Do apply some filters. Think of them even if nobody mentioned any. You surely don't need too old data, you probably don't need data with `price=0` or `quantity=0`, may be something else. Cut off.